# PromQL for calculating high interface bandwidth

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have managed to use the Prom SNMP-Exporter to get the following metrics from Cisco swicthes:

```
ifHCInOctets{ifHCInOctetsIntfBw="1000", ifHCInOctetsIntfDesc="Interface Description", ifHCInOctetsIntfId="104", ifHCInOctetsIntfName="Gi2/0/28", instance="x.x.x.x", job="cisco_intf_poll"}
Value: 66094897366 (in bps)
```

```
ifHighSpeed{ifHCInOctetsIntfId="104", instance="x.x.x.x", job="cisco_intf_poll"}
Value: 10000 (in mbps)
```

The value of `ifHCInOctets` dictates the total number of octets received on the interface. I can get a value in bps by using this Query:

```
rate(ifHCInOctets{instance="x.x.x.x"}[1m]) * 8
```

Then I can run another Query to get the interface top speed, i.e if its a 1gb port or 10gb port.

```
ifHighSpeed{instance="x.x.x.x"}*1000000
```

That returns all the interfaces for the specific instance (switch) and their interface top speed in bps too. It also has `ifHCInOctetsIntfId="x"` which matches the same ID as what I get from the `ifHCInOctets` metric.

What I would like to be able to do, is write a promQL query that gives me all the interfaces that are more than 80 percent utilised, based on their top speed. I have managed to get it working with a static value but cannot work out how to use the value of `ifHighSpeed` to compare, as each interface is different.

I also cannot match the metrics up solely on `instance` or `ifHCInOctetsIntfId` as multiple instances will use the same `ifHCInOctetsIntfId` value. So needs to match both the `instance` and `ifHCInOctetsIntfId` values together to be considered a match.

Looking at the `ifHCInOctets` metric, I have managed to get `ifHCInOctetsIntfBw` in there which is the same value I get from `ifHighSpeed` for that exact interface, but this isn't a value (its a label) so can't work out how to get 80% of it, and that version is in mbps not bps so cant be immediately compared to `ifHCInOctets`. And cant see a way to compare it with the final `ifHCInOctets` value to get only interfaces that are 80% or more utilised.

Im beginning to think writing my own Python exporter for this might be a better bet as I have control of manipulation of the values...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following PromQL query should return network interfaces with utilization exceeding 80% during the last 5 minutes (see `5m` in square brackets inside [rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate)):

```
(
  (8 * rate(ifHCInOctets[5m]))
    / on (instance, ifHCInOctetsIntfId)
  (1e6 * ifHighSpeed)
) > 0.8
```

This query uses `on(...)` modifier, which instructs Prometheus find time series pairs on both sides of `/` operator with the same set of `(instance, ifHCInOctetsIntfId)` labels and then perform per-pair division. See more details about this feature in [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching).

As for the `ifHCInOctetsIntfBw` label at `ifHCInOctets` metric, Prometheus doesn't provide the functionality for extracting numeric values from labels. But you can use an alternative Prometheus-like monitoring system, which supports such functionality. The system is named [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) (I work on it). It provides [label_value](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_value) function for extracting numeric label value and using it in queries. For example, the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query will return interfaces with utilization exceeding 80% during the last 5 minutes (e.g. the same result as the query above):

```
(
  (8 * rate(ifHCInOctets[5m]))
    /
  (1e6 * label_value(ifHCInOctets, "ifHCInOctetsIntfBw"))
) > 0.8
```